# Possible to publish Air for iOS app for in house distribution?

Tags: flash, air, flash-cs5.5

In the "Air for iOS" publish in Flash CS5.5 there is no deployment option for "In House" distribution.

Is there a way to publish and end up with a .ipa that can be used for "In House" distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Flash CS5.5, go to the AIR for iOS Settings > Deployment tab and select "Deployment - Ad hoc". That radio button should really be labeled, "Deployment - Ad hoc or In house".

Answer (score 0):

I came across this solution (you need osx/xcode4 for it to work)
**http://fpstudios.com/2011/08/flash-enterprise-builds/**

A few sidenodes:

- Use the 'Deployment - Apple App store' deployment type
- The author is talking about a .app, but CS5.5 only gives you a .ipa.
  Just rename the .ipa to .zip and extract the contents untill you see a .app file in the /Payload/ folder.
- Also I had to restart xcode4 in order to see the 'newly' created archive.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You don't need Xcode to package an in-house IPA file from Flash CS.